# Resource cost of database per tenant

Tags: sql-server, limits, multi-tenant

I've read that one big disadvantage of the database per tenant model in multi-tenant applications is the extra resource cost of having many (potentially thousands or tens of thousands) databases online at the same time.  What factors affect the number of tenant DB's I can have online at the same time?

Considering that the total amount of data will be (mostly) the same between the DB per tenant and single DB architecture why would a DB per tenant architecture reach the limits faster than a single DB?

I'm using MS SQL Server 2016 but I would be interested to hear answers for other DBMS's as well.

Comment: The limitations will largely depend on your hardware and workload. You could have a single tenant with one user and hit limitations with inadequate hardware.

Comment: This is like asking how many trips to the grocery store will I be able to make with a 1982 Oldsmobile...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Why?  I'm asking what about the multiple DB approach makes it more likely to have resource issues.  The total amount of data will be (mostly) the same with either a separate DB or single DB approach so why is there a bigger performance hit with separate DB?

Comment: You asked *how many DBs before you run into resource limitations.* Nobody can answer this - there is no magic number like 200 or 37 or 552 - it all depends on far too many factors. There have been discussions in the past that are related that you might find useful (e.g. [this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16745/1186) for SQL Server, and [this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16745/1186) for MySQL), but none of them will answer the actual question you've asked.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not asking for an absolute number.  I want to know what the factors which contribute to the number are and why a multiple DB architecture reaches the threshold faster than a single DB one.

Comment: That might be what you're asking **now**, but read your question again please.